# User registration API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Would love some feedback on this simple API implementation with Ruby on Rails. Have I used proper naming conventions, readable/manageable code, optimal approaches, etc? As I'm still learning Ruby on rails, I'd love to hear what other fellow engineers have to say about this :)

**A simple Register API:**

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

class V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    def register
        name = params[:name]
        email = params[:email]
        password = params[:password]

        @existing_user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

        if @existing_user == nil
            @user = User.new(
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                plan: "FREE"
            )
            #save user
            if @user.save!
                #generate auth token
                @auth = save_new_auth @user.id

                render :json => {
                    :user => @user.as_json(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at, :password, :stripe_id, :subscription_id, :id, :email]),
                    :auth => @auth
                }
            else
                render json: {"error" => "Unprocessable Entity"}
            end
        else
            render json: { error: { type: "UNAUTHORIZED", message: "Looks like you already have an account. Please login " } }, status: 403
        end
    end
```

**Login API:**

```rb
def login
    email = params[:email]
    password = params[:password]
    
    @auth = nil
    
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email], password: password)
    
    if @user == nil
        render json: { error: { type: "UNAUTHORIZED", message: "Invalid Login Credentials " } }, status: 401
    else
        @auth = UserAuth.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
        if @auth == nil
            @auth = save_new_auth @user.id
        end
        render :json => {
            :user => @user.as_json(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at, :password, :stripe_id, :subscription_id, :id, :email]),
            :auth => @auth
        }
    end
end
```

**Access token Generator:**

```rb
def save_new_auth (user_id)
    @auth = UserAuth.new(
        access_token: generate_token,
        user_id: user_id,
        status: true
    )
    @auth.save
        return @auth
    end
    
def generate_token(size = 28)
    charset = %w{ 2 3 4 6 7 9 A C D E F G H J K M N P Q R T V W X Y Z}
    (0...size).map{ charset.to_a[rand(charset.size)] }.join
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions

## Non default CRUD action in Controller

It's generally recommended to only have CRUD actions `index, show, new, edit, create, update, destroy` in your controllers. So e.g. you should think about renaming your `register` and `login` actions and extract according controllers.

For example you could have a `UserRegistrationsController` and a `UserLoginsController` which each have a `create` action.

```rb
class V1::UserRegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  end
end

class V1::UserLoginsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  end
end
```

Here is a good blog article explaining this concept
http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/

## Handling user not found

Instead of using `find_by` you could use the bang method `find_by!` which will raise a `RecordNotFound`  error.

```rb
User.find_by!(email: params[:email])
```

Now `RecordNotFound` errors will get automatically translated to a 404 response code. But you could overwrite the default behaviour as well with your own exception app or `rescue_from`

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb#L14
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843373/how-to-deal-with-general-errors-in-rails-api/62846970#62846970

Another possibility is to add a validation with scope so you can only have one email address.

```rb
class V1::UserRegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      plan: "FREE"
    )

    if @user.save
      render @user
    else
      render @user.errors
    end
  end
```

## Strong parameters

User strong parameters instead of plucking the values from the params hash.

```rb
der user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :name)
end
```

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

## Use a PORO or Service object

A lot of people will have different opinions of using a Plain Old Ruby Object vs a Service object etc. But I think a lot of people would agree that it's a good idea to move logic from the controller to a dedicated object.

Example

```
class UserRegistration
  def self.create(params)
    new(params).save
  end

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def save
    user = create_user
    auth = UserAuth.new(
        access_token: generate_token,
        user_id: user.id,
        status: true
    )
    auth if auth.save
  end

  private

  attr_reader :params

  def create_user
    User.create(
      name: params[:name],
      email: params[:email],
      password: params[:password],
      plan: "FREE"
    )
  end

  def generate_token(size = 28)
    charset = %w{ 2 3 4 6 7 9 A C D E F G H J K M N P Q R T V W X Y Z}
    (0...size).map{ charset.to_a[rand(charset.size)] }.join
  end
end
```

And then you can just do in your controller

```rb
class V1::UserRegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if (auth = UserRegistration.create(params))
      render auth
    else
      render :error
    end
  end
end
```

Generally speaking I think there is too much logic in your controllers which makes it hard to read and test.

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you so much for taking the time Christian! I appreciate it! :)

Comment: If you like the answer, please consider to accept it.

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer when talking about using a PORO v Service object, is the idea to create a new controller anytime I need code to do something other than the basic CRUD actions, so the object adheres to basic CRUD actions? I guess i'm a little confused about your `class UserRegistration`; Ideally that's in a controller?